# How can i get the next tables using Tikz? I can´t obtain my text at the top of the figure using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfversion


 \begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw,text width=12cm, text centered,
minimum width=12cm,
minimum height=9cm]at(9,9){Título............................................} ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And how should i compile the next..?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfversion

La emoción primaria y tú como protagonistas

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw,text width=12cm,text justified
minimum width=12cm,
minimum height=9cm]at(0,0){Ahora que ha quedado plasmada la forma en que esta emoción derivada incrementa tu estrés y pone travas a tu desarrollo, te invitamos a escribir una historia diferente. En esta nueva historia tu emoción primaria y tú son los protagonistas. Escribe lo que tú y tu emoción podrían hacer para enfrentar el estrés. Resalta cómo te puede ayudar, en qué momento se debe poner en operación y cuáles serán tus estrategias. ¡Haz tu propia película y ponla en acción! ¿Cómo la titularías?}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry but could you explain your question a little more clearly? I completed your code with `\end{document}` and compiled it but I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: ah, hello! i need my headline at the top of the figure. this is why i am asking for

Comment: What headline? What table? I'm really confused. You have posted code for a picture in TiKZ which consists of a single node. There is no table here that I can see. ? ;)

Comment: ohhh figure, i mean figure

Comment: There's no figure. And now there's a second document. Sorry. But this is making no sense. For a figure, you could use `\begin{figure}\caption{Your caption}\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\end{figure}`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: If you have 2 questions, ask 2 questions. Do not combine them. (I am too confused to be sure whether you have 1 question or 2 so this may not apply. But if it does, asking them separately will also help to clear things up a bit.)

Comment: this is exactly what i mean, the {tikzpicture}

Comment: So can you use that code? Wrap it in the `figure` environment and use `\caption{}`?

Comment: I'm illustrating the figure of a page to simulate a manual or on a table

Comment: How are the two documents related? Is it that you want to include a picture of one in the other? That is, one is the 'manual', say, and the other is your main document in which you want to include a picture of that manual?

Comment: In the second case, you need a `;` at the end of the line. You also need to remove `text justified` as there is no such key. Can you post a picture of what you are trying to do? Just posting a picture is bad but posting a picture as well as the code you've got would help people to understand your question.

Comment: @cfr What I understand is that she needs to emulate a page of a manual inside the page of the document (in this case a book), so she's using `Tikz` trying to draw that page... as a table or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{book}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \pgfversion
 \flushleft
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[draw,text width=12cm, text centered,
  minimum width=12cm,
  minimum height=3cm]at(9,9){Título............................................\\ And how  should i compile the next..?} ;
 \pgfversion
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \flushleft
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[draw,text width=12cm,text justified
 minimum width=12cm,
 minimum height=9cm]at(0,0){Ahora que ha quedado plasmada la forma en que esta emoción derivada incrementa tu estrés y pone travas a tu desarrollo, te invitamos a escribir una historia diferente. En esta nueva historia tu emoción primaria y tú son los protagonistas. Escribe lo que tú y tu emoción podrían hacer para enfrentar el estrés. Resalta cómo te puede ayudar, en qué momento se debe poner en operación y cuáles serán tus estrategias. ¡Haz tu propia película y ponla en acción! ¿Cómo la titularías?}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 La emoción primaria y tú como protagonistas
 \end{document}
```

Output:
[image: tikz]

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question